# where to define customemail_email_template in magento2 to send mail to admin

Tags: magento2

hello everyone I am getting error Email template 'customemail_email_template' is not defined. where to define it 
[image]

Comment: Did you create any module for wholesale enquiries? If yes then check from where you are sending email with template and create email template with that id. Also can you post you email_templates.xml and the code from where you are sending email.?

Comment: no  i have does not create any template for it

Comment: if you want i can send my module to you for review

Comment: Can you post the code of your module from where you are sending email? Yes please post it.

Comment: please give my your mail id i will send you my module and review it here whole code is not dcoming

Comment: @SukumarGorai Gorai which file code you want?

Comment: Come to discussion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90026/discussion-between-ashish-ramchandani-and-sukumar-gorai).

Answer (score 0):

Follow this blog in your module
https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-create-custom-email-templates/

Comment: this blog has a different thing then my module

Comment: Can you post your email_templates.xml code here.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
       <template id="customemail_email_template" label=" Your Custom Label" file="customemail_email_template.html" type="html" module="Magneto_WholesaleApplication" area="frontend"/>
</config>

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example module which has a configuration option with a custom email template and a basic helper to send the email.

> https://mage2gen.com/load/e4822a13-a700-4372-b5d0-9704cf436f8d?main_version=2

[image]